# Error when trying to connect to access database in C# for project

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a project that will read, write,and check for duplicates in my access data base file. I am using C# and keep getting "Connection failed error that I have written into the program if the connection state = 0. If anyone can offer any help I would appreciate it. I am using Access 2016 and I am not sure what references I need for my project (if any). Everything I have found online is either outdated or doesn't work.

Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;


 namespace RHG
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Users\grosales\Documents\rhg\RHG\Used.accdb"))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("connected");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("connection failed");
            }
        }

    }
```

`

Comment: where are you opening your connection?

Comment: have you taken a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-and-modifying-data

Comment: You are not opening the conneciton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not opened the connection.

```
connection.Open();
```

Note: Checking the connection state is not enough. You might get an exception when trying to open the connection. Enclose it in try-catch instead.

It is also a good practice to enclose work on a connection with `using`

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection()) {
    connection.ConnectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Users\...\Used.accdb";
    try {
        connection.Open();

        //TODO: do something with the connection

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This ensures that the connection will be closed and the resources be released.

Comment: Tried that, still wouldn't connect

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: I have updated the code in the original question since I couldn't figure out how to post it on here. I'm not getting an exception

Comment: How do you know that it didn't work then? If you are getting the message `"connection failed"`, then you got an exception that you swallowed. Try adding `ex.Message` to your message as I have shown in my anwser. You should not replace the original question, as this invalides all the comments and answers given to that point. However, you are welcome in adding additional information to the question.

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the code to your specs and are getting the error "unrecognized database format" not sure why. I recreated the file like 5 times

Comment: Probably you connection string is wrong. See: [https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).

Comment: I got it, turns out I needed to use a different connection string. Thank you! is there a good method to let me know if the database is connected? I was thinking a if else statement

Comment: If you don't get an exception, when opening it, then it is connected. Instead of keeping it open all the time your application runs, create a new connection each time you need one (the using-statement ensures that it is closed every time). The physical connection is pooled, i.e. kept open automatically, so this not much overhead and reduces the active connections in multi-user environments. Like this you can always use try-catch instead of if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

You're missing the connection.Open(); statement, which should be wrapped in a try catch.

Additionally, you can specify the connection string within the constructor, like

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Users\grosales\Documents\rhg\RHG\Used.accdb")) 
{
    //do DB access here
}
//no need to call connection.Close() - it's automatically done once you leave the using block.
```

Comment: Thanks man, I have posted the updated code, still not working. Definitely my fault I am sure